# JavaScript responseText not being saved as varaible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am using Ajax to run a PHP script within my site.  I would like to set a JS variable to the response from the PHP script.

This script should make the variable "stopAt" set to 42.

Here is my error:
[image: Error]

Here is my code:

```
            function reqListener () {
            console.log(this.responseText);
            }

            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
            oReq.onload = function() {
                var stopAt = (this.responseText)
            };
            oReq.open("get", "gennum.php", true);                               
            oReq.send();
            theWheel.animation.stopAngle = stopAt;
```

Here is gennum.php:

```
<?php
echo json_encode(42);
?>
```

Thanks!  Hopefully you guys can solve my problem!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stopAt` is a local variable. It is only defined inside the function. You need to move statement that use it into the function.

```
oReq.onload = function() {
    var stopAt = (this.responseText);
    theWheel.animation.stopAngle = stopAt;
};
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this by using a global variable... or something?

Comment: You will still need to set `stopAngle` inside the function. [`XMLHttpRequest.send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) is asyncronous, so it will return as soon as possible without waiting request to complete, and the variable will still not defined below `send()` call.

Comment: @jake..........

Comment: I got it to work!  Thank you so much for your help!  You are a great part of this community!  :)